# How to assign product category during products import

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category, product-attribute, import

I've to import some products from a txt file where, for every row, there's product sku, product name, product description, short description, price and category id.
The products are imported but price and quantity aren't set and the products aren't assigned to categories.
The code I use is the following:

```
include_once('C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php');

Mage::app('admin');

$rootMagento = Mage::getBaseDir();
$files = scandir($rootMagento);
$count = sizeof($files);
for ($i =0; $i< $count; $i++) {
    if ($files[$i] == 'productData.txt') {   //i_12345678.txt
        //$fileAperto = fopen($files[$i], "r");
        $righe = file('productData.txt');
        $countRighe = sizeof($righe);
        for ($ii = 0; $ii < $countRighe; $ii++) {
            list($sku, $name, $description, $shortDescription, $price, $categoryId) = split("[';']", $righe[$ii]);
            if ($sku == '' || $name == '' || $description == '' 
                || $shortDescription == '' ||  $price == '') {
                Mage::log('esportazione non corretta: manca uno dei dati');
            } 
            $product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $productId = $product_model->getIdBySku($sku);
            if (!$productId) {
                //inserimento
                /*
                $productData = array(
                    'sku' => $sku,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'description' => $description,
                    'short_description' => $shortDescription,
                    'status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED,
                    'visibility' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                    'attribute_set_id' => 10
                );
                */
                $product_model->setSku($sku);
                $product_model->setName($name);
                $product_model->setDescription($description);
                $product_model->setShortDescription($shortDescription);
                $product_model->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                $product_model->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
                $product_model->setAttributeSetId(10);
                $product_model->setPrice($price);
                $product_model->setCategoryId($categoryId);
                $qty = 1;
                try {
                    $productId = $product_model->save()->getId();
                    $product = $product_model->load($productId);
                    $product->setQty($qty);
                    $product->setIsInStock(1); //->isInStock(1)
                    $product->save();
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                //aggiornamento
                $product = $product_model->load($productId);
                $productData = array (
                    'sku' => $sku,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'description' => $description,
                    'short_description' => $shortDescription,
                    'status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED ,
                    'visibility' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                    'attribute_set_id' => 10
                );
                $product->setData($productData); // + codice x stock
                $qty = 1;
                try {
                    $productId = $product->save()->getId();
                    $product = $product_model->load($productId);
                    $product->setQty($qty);
                    $product->setIsInStock(1); //->isInStock(1)
                    $product->save();
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        //fclose($fileAperto);
    } 
}
```

Why I don't try to set price, quantity and category also? 
Can you help me, please?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

I dont know But you have to use

`$product_model->setCategoryIds($categoryId)`

instead of

`$product:model->setCategoryId($categoryId);`

Please try and let me know.

Comment: I've this error: 'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid category IDs.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php:595 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php(357): Mage::throwException('Invalid categor...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\prova3.php(43): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->setCategoryIds(NULL) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 595'

Comment: Category Ids should be in array

Comment: product is not yet assigned to category..

Comment: Provide me updated code what you try

Comment: $categoriesIds[] = $categoryId;
$product_model->setCategoryIds($categoriesIds);

Comment: please reindex and check again

Comment: now the product is assigned to the category!! thank you very much!! Do you know why price and quantity attributes aren't set?

Comment: You are always welcome, If Its help you then mark My answer as accepted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45048/discussion-between-federica-and-murtuza-zabuawala).